# Duda sencilla SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, tablas

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes registros (los campos son Fórmula - Base):

F1 - B1

F1 - B2

F1 - B3

F2 - B1

F2 - B2

F3 - B1

F3 - B2

F3 - B4

Lo que quiero es que me seleccione qué fórmulas contienen las bases B1,B2 y B3.

Me tiene que mostrar las formulas que contengan estas tres bases o menos, siempre y cuando la fórmula no tenga una base que no sean esas tres (por ejemplo la F3 tiene B4, por lo cual no deberia mostrar F3).

Tengo conocimientos muy básicos de instrucciones SQL, agradeceria si alguien me pudiera echar una mano.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos?

Comment: Puedes incluir la estructura de tu table..?

Comment: Creo que el motor de la bbdd y la estructura no son necesarias, simplemente necesito saber como seria la instruccion SELECT.

Comment: Las soluciones que se te pueden ofrecer suelen ser muy distintas de motor a motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te planteo una solución relativamente ANSI, aunque la implementación del ejemplo es netamente SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE ( 
    Formula CHAR(2),
    Base CHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla (Formula, Base)
    SELECT 'F1', 'B1' UNION
    SELECT 'F1', 'B2' UNION
    SELECT 'F1', 'B3' UNION
    SELECT 'F2', 'B1' UNION
    SELECT 'F2', 'B2' UNION
    SELECT 'F3', 'B1' UNION
    SELECT 'F3', 'B2' UNION
    SELECT 'F3', 'B4'

SELECT  DISTINCT Formula 
    FROM @Tabla
    WHERE Base IN ('B1', 'B2', 'B3')
        AND Formula NOT IN (SELECT  DISTINCT Formula 
                    FROM @Tabla
                    WHERE Base not IN ('B1', 'B2', 'B3'))


Formula
-------
F1
F2
```

#### Explicación:

- Obtenemos las formulas que tengan alguna de bases definidas
- Quitamos mediante una subconsulta, aquellas formulas que tengan además alguna otra base de las definidas